# Why does Spyder want to save my *.py file when I run script?

Tags: python, save, spyder

I've searched on stackoverflow and Googled but don't see the following issue addressed.

Using Python 3.5 on Spyder, when I hit the Run button to execute the script in an **ALREADY** saved .py file a Save File window pops up twice. All I have to do is hit Cancel twice to run the script, so not a big problem, but it's irksome.

For example, Save File opens when I try to execute:

```
def summing(s,p):
    return s + p
print(summing(1,2))
```

However, when I highlight the code and right-click on "Run selection or current line" the script simply executes (no Save File window pops up).

How can I stop Save File windows from opening when I hit the Run button?

Comment: I have the same problem! need to rebote spyder for it to go away

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Spyder requires that all open files are saved (the tabs on the upper left of the user interface), not just the active script you are running.  Once all tabs are properly saved the code will run with no save file prompt.